# Why does GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS not work in docker container?

Tags: docker, gcloud, gsutil

`gsutil cp` doesn't work in container but work well in local:

## 1. local (ubuntu 22.04)

```bash
$ ls -alh /tmp/credential.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 rightx2 rightx2 2.3K Aug 18 20:50 /tmp/credential.json

$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/credential.json

$ gsutil cp gs://my_project/13.parquet ./
Copying gs://my_project/13.parquet...
- [1 files][359.3 KiB/359.3 KiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/359.3 KiB.
```

## 2. Docker container

### 2.1 Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# gsutil
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin

COPY /tmp/credential.json /tmp/credential.json
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/credential.json
```

### 2.2 Inside container

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it  wow/my_image  bash
```

```bash
root@26a0fb9ecade:/# ls -alh /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4.0K Aug 18 11:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Aug 18 13:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K Aug  4 07:43 credential.json

root@26a0fb9ecade:/# echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
/tmp/credential.json


root@26a0fb9ecade:/# gsutil cp gs://my_project/13.parquet ./
ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

I don't see why it raise `ServiceException`. I've checked both credential files are same as well...

Comment: 1) **Anonymous caller** means the CLI is not using the credentials you set up. The CLI does not use the environment variable. One way to verify the problem is to run `gcloud auth list`. 2) Add this command to your container: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/tmp/credential.json` before using `gsutil`.

Comment: `COPY`'ing credentials (`credentials.json`) into a container image is a security risk. Anyone that is able to acquire the container image can use the Service Account key to authenticate requests.

Comment: @DazWilkin has a good point. Consider a Docker volume mount for /tmp/credential.json so that the credentials are not part of the container image except at runtime.

Comment: @DazWilkin You're definitely right. But this is just for the test integration test in local env.